# GPU sync failed when run two .py files at the same time in Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

I was using Pycharm to run `A.py`, and when I started to run another `B.py` file under the same project, I got the errors about `A.py`, says:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: GPU sync failed`

The two files both use tensorflow-GPU, and this error does not show everytime i started to run the second file.

Does anyone have any idea about the cause? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the most common reason may be that your GPU is out of memory.Then allowing memory growth can help.

It can be done by calling `[tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth][1]` which attempts to allocate only as much GPU memory as needed for the runtime allocations.

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
try:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
except RuntimeError as e:
  # Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
  print(e)
```